# ¿Cómo hago para tener un input required seleccionado después de dar click a un submit?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

Espero ser claro.

Tengo un `textarea` y con javascript le doy el atributo `required`, y cuando le doy click al botón **submit** cuando no hay información escrita, aparece la alerta.(oculta)

Todo normal, pero lo que quiero es que después de que aparezca esta alerta oculta, el `textarea` este listo para escribir en el, y no tengas que darle click.

Uso este código para intentar ese click pero no me funciona:

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["input"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        if( ! ("autofocus" in document.createElement( "input" ) ) )
 {
 document.getElementById( "input" ).focus();
 }
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Pero si me funciona al cargar la pagina que esté el textarea clickeado con este código:

```
 <script>
 if( ! ("autofocus" in document.createElement( "input" ) ) )
 {
 document.getElementById( "input" ).focus();
 }
 </script>
```

Mi formulario es este:

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="upload.php"  onsubmit="return validateForm()" autocomplete="off">
<div id="txtar1"><textarea rows="34" cols="165" type="text" name="input" pattern=".{10,}" autofocus></textarea></div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="save1"><input type="submit" class="save-b" value="Save" /></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Podrías mostrar el formulario que tienes.

Comment: <form name="myForm" method="post" action="upload.php"  onsubmit="return validateForm()" autocomplete="off">
<div id="txtar1"><textarea rows="34" cols="165" type="text" name="input" pattern=".{10,}" autofocus></textarea></div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="save1"><input type="submit" class="save-b" value="Save" /></div>
</form>

Comment: Dale en editar pregunta y agrégalo por favor :)

Comment: listo, ya lo añadí

Comment: Creo que ya detecto el problema, dame un momento hago una prueba rápida en https://jsfiddle.net/ y te dejo la respuesta con el soporte de la misma listo.

Comment: Yo probe el codigo en el chrome y en el mozilla y si lo selecciona

Comment: @Aspoky, en tu pregunta el `textarea` no tiene el atributo `required`, pero tiene `pattern` el cual no es soportado por `textarea`. Tampoco puedo ver que aparezca ningún alerta. Sinceramente no esta claro, porque preguntas cosas que no suceden con el código que presentas

Comment: @Marcos la alerta la he ocultado con javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Hola! Para qué se está usando esta linea?

```
if( ! ("autofocus" in document.createElement( "input" ) ) )
```

Con lo siguiente te debería quedar bien:

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["input"].value;
if (x == "") {
    document.getElementById( "input" ).focus();
    return false;
}
}
</script>

<form name="myForm" method="post" action="upload.php"  onsubmit="return validateForm()" autocomplete="off">
<div id="txtar1"><textarea id="input" rows="34" cols="165" type="text"     name="input" pattern=".{10,}" autofocus></textarea></div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="save1"><input type="submit" class="save-b" value="Save" /></div>
</form>
```

Faltaba id en textarea, revisa que sea único, "input" no es un buen id. Esto es solo un ejemplo. También si esto es web te recomendaría usar jQuery: https://jquery.com/

¡Saludos y éxito!

Comment: ¡Gracias, tu solución y la de @Andres son correctas las ambas!

Answer (score 0):

El problema como mencionaba Sebastian lo tienes en la condición: `if( ! ("autofocus" in document.createElement( "input" ) ) )`

Para solucionarlo e modificado tu función de la siguiente manera:

**Formulario:**

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="upload.php"  onsubmit="return validateForm()" autocomplete="off">
<div id="txtar1"><textarea rows="34" cols="165" type="text" id="input" name="input"  ></textarea></div>
<br>
<br>
<div id="save1"><input type="submit" class="save-b" value="Save" /></div>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["input"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        if(document.activeElement.name == false)
        {
            document.getElementById("input").focus();                
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Espero te haya sido de ayuda y solucionado tu problema, no olvides calificar la respuesta de manera positiva en caso de que te haya ayudado y si resolvio tu problema no te olvides de check :)

Comment: ¡Justo lo que buscaba!

Comment: apruebo la respuesta de @Sebastin Araya porque es más corta y ocupa menos bytes de documento, pero he probado esta y también funciona